# How to make this MySQL query faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a MySQL table:

Structure: [image: Structure]

Content: [image: Content]

I need to make this query:

```
SELECT * FROM line WHERE id_user='879930883' AND dt IS NOT NULL ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT 6
```

`id_user` is always different. This query takes about 2 seconds.

How can I make the query faster?

**Edit:** 
This is the output of EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM line WHERE id_user='879930883' AND dt IS NOT NULL ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT 6:
[image: Output of EXPLAIN]

```
CREATE TABLE `line` (
 `id_line` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_media` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `img` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
 `feed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `tag` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `done` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `dt` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id_line`),
 KEY `idx_line_3` (`id_user`,`dt`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=620793 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: it seems that the column `done` could be removed. It's value seems to be equivalent to `dt IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @VMai . . . That is a good observation and might lead to a simplification of the query.

Comment: @VMai here is my 'SHOW CREATE TABLE line'

Answer (score 4):

You can make this faster by creating an index.  In this case:

```
create index idx_line_3 on line(id_user, done, dt);
```

EDIT:

For the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM line
WHERE id_user = '879930883' AND dt IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY dt DESC
LIMIT 6 ;
```

You want the following index:

```
create index idx_line_2 on line(id_user, dt);
```

However, I'm not 100% sure it will use the index for the `order by`, so check the `explain` plan for the query.  If it is doing a file sort, then you can fix the query by filtering the `NULL` values second:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM (SELECT l.*
      FROM line l
      WHERE id_user = '879930883' 
      ORDER BY dt DESC
      LIMIT 6
     ) l
WHERE dt IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY dt DESC;
```

The `order by dt desc` puts the `NULL` values last.

Comment: I would reverse the order of `dt` and `done`. The column `done` doesn't seem very selective.

Comment: @VMai . . . You can reverse them, but then the index would not be optimal for the query.  The `where` clause conditions are evaluated before the `order by` conditions.  Hence, they need to be in the index before the `order by` conditions.

Comment: If my speculation about the direct relationship between `done` and `dt` would be right, he could simply replace `done=1` with `dt IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @VMai . . . With the query written in the question, the index with all three columns is the best index for the `where` and `order by` clauses.  If you change the query, another index might be best.

Comment: You're right. I missed the processing order first. But if rewriting of the query would produce the same result then he could give it a try.

Comment: @gordon-linoff then I make index create index idx_line_3 on line(id_user, dt)

Comment: But my query still takes about 1.3 seconds: SELECT * 
FROM line
WHERE id_user =  '879930883'
AND dt IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY dt DESC 
LIMIT 6

Comment: @user3634110 What is the result of [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) <your query>?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Your rewrite with the subselect seems very promising. But I don't understand the output of explain at all. I think user3634110 should post the current table definiton.

Comment: @user3634110: Please copy the output that you get in phpMyAdmin simply as text to your question. You could use: `SHOW CREATE TABLE line` to get this including the indexes.

Comment: OK, your query is using the best possible index. Please try the newest statement of Gordon Linoff.

Comment: @VMai query still takes about 2 seconds